# How do you fix the group by requirement in sql queries?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT A.Emp_ID, A.Emp_Name 
FROM Employee A 
INNER JOIN Assignment B on A.Emp_ID = B.Emp_ID 
WHERE B.Emp_ID 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Which returned the error:

> SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by Emp_ID' at line 1

I looked it up and found a post on here that talked about it, and what to do.

I changed it to this:

```
SELECT A.Emp_ID, A.Emp_Name 
FROM Employee A 
INNER JOIN Assignment B ON A.Emp_ID = B.Emp_ID 
WHERE B.Emp_ID 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
GROUP BY Emp_ID;
```

Which, to me, looks exactly like it is supposed to, so I'm confused why it doesn't work. Can someone help me straighten this out please?

Thank you.

Comment: Incidentally, the error message relates to a different query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you want:

```
SELECT e.Emp_ID, e.Emp_Name
FROM Employee e INNER JOIN 
     Assignment a
     ON e.Emp_ID = a.Emp_ID 
GROUP BY e.Emp_ID, e.Emp_Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Notes:

- The `WHERE` clause is useless.
- You need a `GROUP BY`.
- Use meaningful table aliases rather than arbitrary letters.

Comment: Thank you. I will check this answer after the timer is up.

Answer (score 0):

group by before having

```
SELECT A.Emp_ID, A.Emp_Name FROM Employee A INNER JOIN 
Assignment B on A.Emp_ID = B.Emp_ID
group by A.Emp_ID, A.Emp_Name
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```